# Blogger Atom Output all post feeds

Tags: blogger

I know the default blogger atom is www.[yourdomian].blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default, but how could get all posts feeds? I found a semi-solution is to add "max-results=500" (or change the number bigger)

Just wondering is there any better solution for all post feeds?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there are more than 500 posts on the blog,  then hope that no individual category (label) 
has more than 500 posts, and get the feed of each category.

http://support.google.com/blogger/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=97933

Beyond that, you can use either start-index or published-min and published-max.

A large number of items in feedburner is not really as option, unless each item only 
contains a very short summary, so as not to exceed feedburner 512KB limit.

http://support.google.com/feedburner/answer/79009/?hl=en

Something that will only work for some Blogger-based blogs - those that someone has 
subscribed to via Google Reader early enough after the first ever post;
Then you can get the Google Reader cached atom feed from the very beginning,
will have to load a different URL every one thousand items.

```
http://www.google.com/reader/atom/feed/http://<BloggerBlog>/feeds/posts/default?n=1000
```

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/26567/how-to-raise-google-reader-rss-feed-entry-limit

Comment: https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol#RetrievingWithQuery

Answer (score 2):

Yes, www.[yourdomian].blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?max-results=500 is the only way to go.
You can burn your feed to feedburner either.